# Retrieve json parameters in current URL with php (and same name parameters)

Tags: php, json

I found lots of issues dealing with this kind of situation, but none like mine. Or maybe it was that I did not send the correct parameters via ajax?

This question is the following [of that issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262201/get-the-correct-number-of-objects-when-sending-a-form-with-jquery)

Here is the ajax code

```
$('.valide').unbind().click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var recupChoices= $('tr').map(function() {
    var $row = $(this);
    return {
        idenR: $row.data('id'),
        duree: $row.find($("select[name='chooseDuration']")).val()
    };
  }).get();

  choices = (JSON.stringify(recupChoices));

  $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url  : "ajax/order.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data : choices ,
    success: function(data) {
      // Show success or fail messages
    }
  });
});
```

I suppose that I have chosen the standard values and the first id and I choose the GET method to see the URL parameters. This URL sent via AJAX will be :

```
http://[sitename]/ajax/order.php?[{%22idenR%22:1,%22duree%22:%221%22},{%22idenR%22:2,%22duree%22:%221%22}]
```

Already, from there, is that I make a mistake?

Then I can't at all to get the parameters in the file order.php. I tried to do that :

```
$currentURL= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$data = file_get_contents($currentURL);
var_dump(data);
// But it return "null"
```

I can't get the parameters or I was wrong before ... but where ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error. If you come across such cases, just remember that you must add a parameter to the data you send. I made a mistake in thinking that I already was sending parameters, while they were already encode with JSON.

In my example, you just have to add a name (here "datas") like this `data : {datas : choice}` in the AJAX request.

Here is **the working code** :

```
$.ajax({
  type : "GET",
  url  : "ajax/order.php",
  dataType: "JSON",
  data : {datas : choices} ,
  success: function(data) {
    // Show success or fail messages
  }
});
```